# Updating value with react hook from select with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble with `react-bootstrap` (or more likely this is a problem with `JavaScript`).
I'm using a select with dynamically loaded content. Selecting some element updates the `id` hook. But if I don't select anything (for example if here is only one element in the list) `id` hook doesn't get updated. What is the best solution to update hook with actual value of select even if it hasn't been touched by user?

I'm thinking of manually launching `onChange` event after the form is loaded or adding a default empty disabled `option` to my `select`.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```js
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
const [id, setId] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);

async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const data=await getAll();
        setCategories(data)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

export interface Category{
    id:number,
    name:string
}

<Form.Control as="select" onChange={(e) => setId(parseInt(e.target.value))}>
    {categories.map((category: Category) => {
        return <option value={category.id}>{category.name}</option>;
    })}
</Form.Control>
```

Comment: How about you `setId()` to the first element of the array after you fetch the data in `fetchData`?

Comment: @kunquan, Tried your solution: updated `const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);` to `const [categories, setCategories] = useState<Category[]>([]);` Added `.then(() => setId(categories[0].id));` after `fetchData` , now I get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): categories[0] is undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

> now I get Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): categories[0] is undefined

It's expected as in the function `fetchData` now the `categories` value is `[]` and not the value you just set (why this is the case read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately). In short the function will use the component state value at the time the function state and it will keep this value until the function exit)
So you can fix your code by doing this instead

```
async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const data=await getAll();
        setCategories(data)
        setId(data[0].id)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
}
```